# Cast Session terminates with error code 2005

Tags: android, google-cast

I am trying to build a very basic, proof-of-concept cast application, and my Cast Session keeps ending for error code 2005 APPLICATION_NOT_RUNNING.

Using the Default Media Receiver Application ID works. The session connects just fine and plays the content.

However, with the app ID registered as a Remote Display Receiver via Google Cast SDK Developer Console, the cast session terminates abruptly after starting as shown in the logs:

```
12-02 11:51:12.458 19515-8203/? I/CastService: [instance-65] onApplicationConnected: com.company.app applicationId: 80F9586X, name: Company, images.count: 0, namespaces.count: 4, senderAppIdentifier: null, senderAppLaunchUrl: null Flipgrid 8c487445-82cc-4801-8c5d-8084cfacb4dd true
12-02 11:51:12.489 19068-19068/com.company.app W/CastActivity: onSessionStarted
12-02 11:51:12.563 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0291 RCNController] calling Listener.onConnected(true)
12-02 11:51:12.608 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0291 RCNController] joinApplicationInternal: appId:80F9586X sessionId: joinOptions:joinOptions(connectionType=INVISIBLE)
12-02 11:51:12.620 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0291 RCNController] joinApplicationInternal: appId:80F9586X sessionId: joinOptions:joinOptions(connectionType=INVISIBLE)
12-02 11:51:12.627 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0291 RCNController] finishDisconnecting; socketError="0 No error", mDisconnectStatusCode=SUCCESS
12-02 11:51:12.627 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0291 RCNController] listener.onDisconnected(SUCCESS)
12-02 11:51:13.159 946-1701/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 142]
12-02 11:51:13.588 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0292 RCNController] calling Listener.onConnected(true)
12-02 11:51:13.629 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0292 RCNController] joinApplicationInternal: appId:80F9586X sessionId: joinOptions:joinOptions(connectionType=INVISIBLE)
12-02 11:51:13.643 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0292 RCNController] joinApplicationInternal: appId:80F9586X sessionId: joinOptions:joinOptions(connectionType=INVISIBLE)
12-02 11:51:13.652 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0292 RCNController] finishDisconnecting; socketError="0 No error", mDisconnectStatusCode=SUCCESS
12-02 11:51:13.652 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0292 RCNController] listener.onDisconnected(SUCCESS)
12-02 11:51:15.068 377-1305/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback speaker
12-02 11:51:15.072 377-1305/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
12-02 11:51:17.590 19515-8203/? I/CastDeviceController: [controller-0289 API] listener.onApplicationDisconnected(APPLICATION_NOT_RUNNING)
12-02 11:51:17.593 19515-8203/? I/CastService: [instance-65] onApplicationDisconnected: com.company.app 8c487445-82cc-4801-8c5d-8084cfacb4dd APPLICATION_NOT_RUNNING
12-02 11:51:17.596 19068-19068/com.company.app E/AudioAttributes: Invalid stream type -1 for AudioAttributes`
12-02 11:51:17.696 19068-19068/com.company.app W/CastActivity: onSessionEnded error=2005 APPLICATION_NOT_RUNNING
```

Any ideas as to what might be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are playing a media and not doing RemoteDisplay (which seems to be the case), you should either use a Styled receiver, Default receiver or your own custom receiver; the Remote Display Receiver is for Remote Display APIs (which allows you to present a view from your sender app on the TV) and not for a regular cast application.